# How to use if-else in karate UI automation

Tags: karate

I need to implement a condition in my feature that:
if a particular element (says >USERNAME) is exist, it inputs the value in Username field.
Else reload the page once and again wait for user name.

As in application some times page get freeze and I need to reload the same to get login screen.
I have gone through with Conditional logic "https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic" but not able to understand much here. Please help.

Comment: read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#optional

Comment: Thanks for the response and I already tried that option. But issue is how to handle ELSE condition if element to not exists i need a reload of page. As I am using ```* retry(10).waitFor(loginPage.username)``` and need a reload of page if this fails.

Comment: it is just normal JS: `* if (!exists('blah')) doSomething()`